# Accidentally Deleted Synergy Applet Linux Mint

Tags: synergy

I accidentally deleted the Synergy applet that was on the bottom panel on Linux Mint. Now it won't show up when I run the program. How do I get it back? I know this is not Synergy-specific, but I couldn't find what I was looking for with Google searches.

Comment: Can you reinstall it in software manager?

Comment: @Alexiy I have tried that, but it didn't work

Comment: Where there any error messages given by the software manager?

Comment: No there were not, but the problem was not with synergy or the package installer.

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was add The "System Tray" applet back to the panel. Good as new!